Javascript automatically add attribute "d__=" to table td when clicked quickly after load
I've a problem with javascript on a table, when a user click on a tr element of a table the row change class and the other rows return to the old class with this code:
 $(document).on("mousedown", "#orders_products_table > tr", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let product = $(this).children("td").eq(0).text();
        let category = $("#orders_categoriesbt").text();
        switch(e.which){
            case 1:
                if(!$(this).is(":first-child")){
                    $("#orders_products_table > tr").removeClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    $(this).addClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    LoadAdditions(category, product);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(!$(this).is(":first-child")){
                    $("#orders_products_table > tr").removeClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    $(this).addClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    $(this).contextmenu(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#orders-context-menu").css("display", "block");
                        if((e.pageX + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) >= $(window).width() && (e.pageY + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) >= $(window).height()){
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: (e.pageY - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) + "px",
                                left: (e.pageX - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) + "px"
                            });
                        }else if((e.pageX + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) >= $(window).width() && (e.pageY + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) < $(window).height()){
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: e.pageY + "px",
                                left: (e.pageX - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) + "px"
                            });
                        }else if((e.pageX + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) < $(window).width() && (e.pageY + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) > $(window).height()){
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: (e.pageY - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) + "px",
                                left: e.pageX + "px"
                            });
                        }else{
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: e.pageY + "px",
                                left: e.pageX + "px"
                            });
                        }
                        row_selected = $(this);
                    });
                }
                break;
        }

The table is generated dynamically with an ajax call to a Flask server, but if the row is clicked before a second after it was generated, in the DOM automatically appear d__="" attribute on TD and change the text color from green to black.
Picture
HTML
<div id="div-center-products-tables">
            <div id="div-center-products-tables-products">
                <table id="orders_products_table" class="principal-table"></table>
            </div>
            <div id="div-center-products-tables-additions">
                <h3 class="principal-h1">{{langorders[session['lang']]['additions-title']}}</h3>
                <div id="div-center-products-tables-additions-contents"></div>
            </div>
        </div>

I've forced removing of attribute after 2 seconds and it works, but I don't like as a solution.
function removeautoattr(){
    $("#orders_products_table > tr").children("td").removeAttr("d__");
}

function LoadProducts(category){
    $.ajax({
        type:"GET",
        url: "/orderspage_loadproducts",
        headers:{
            "Content-type":"application/json", 
            "Accept":"application/json"
        },
        data:{
            p_category: category
        },
        success:function(response){
            $("#orders_products_table").html(response["html"]);
            setTimeout(removeautoattr, 2000);
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error){
            console.error(xhr);
        }
    });
}

Load Addition code
function LoadAdditions(category, product){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/orderspage_loadadditions",
        data:{
            p_category: category,
            p_product: product
        },
        success: function(response){
            if(response["html"] == "none"){
                $("#div-center-products-tables-additions-contents").html("");
            }else{
                $("#div-center-products-tables-additions-contents").html(response["html"]);
            }
        },
        error:function(xhr, status, error){
            console.error(xhr);
        }
    });
}

Anyone know why d__ is automatically added to the DOM? Thanks in advance.
I made a timer to remove attribute d__ after 2 seconds, or block the function for 2 seconds before the user can click. Both works but I don't like the solution.

could you share LoadAdditions code please? is the bug triggered by both l/r buttons or just the left one?

not related but you can keep your code more dry if you only compute top/left values in the elif block, and change your css only once at the end of the block

I've edited with LoadAdditions code, but I don't think the problem is in that part of code, because it works perfectly without any bug. Yes left or right click result in the same bug.

The d__ attribute you're seeing is likely due to an internal behavior or bug in a library you're using. It's unusual for standard JavaScript or jQuery to add such attributes on its own. Here are a few steps to troubleshoot and resolve this issue:

Check for Library Conflicts: Ensure that you don't have conflicting libraries that might be manipulating the DOM. Check all included scripts and their versions.
Isolate the Issue: Simplify your code to isolate the problem. Remove other scripts and styles to see if the issue persists.
Use MutationObserver: Instead of setting a timeout to remove the attribute, you can use MutationObserver to watch for changes and remove the attribute immediately when it's added.

Here is an example of how you can use MutationObserver:
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "d__") {
            mutation.target.removeAttribute("d__");
        }
    });
});

const table = document.getElementById("orders_products_table");

const config = { attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ["d__"] };

observer.observe(table, config);

Here is a revised version of your JavaScript to include the MutationObserver:
$(document).ready(function() {
    const observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
        mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
            if (mutation.type === "attributes" && mutation.attributeName === "d__") {
                mutation.target.removeAttribute("d__");
            }
        });
    });

    const table = document.getElementById("orders_products_table");

    const config = { attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeFilter: ["d__"] };

    observer.observe(table, config);

    $(document).on("mousedown", "#orders_products_table > tr", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        let product = $(this).children("td").eq(0).text();
        let category = $("#orders_categoriesbt").text();
        switch(e.which){
            case 1:
                if(!$(this).is(":first-child")){
                    $("#orders_products_table > tr").removeClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    $(this).addClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    LoadAdditions(category, product);
                }
                break;
            case 3:
                if(!$(this).is(":first-child")){
                    $("#orders_products_table > tr").removeClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    $(this).addClass("principal-tr-yellow");
                    $(this).contextmenu(function(e){
                        e.preventDefault();
                        $("#orders-context-menu").css("display", "block");
                        if((e.pageX + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) >= $(window).width() && (e.pageY + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) >= $(window).height()){
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: (e.pageY - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) + "px",
                                left: (e.pageX - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) + "px"
                            });
                        }else if((e.pageX + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) >= $(window).width() && (e.pageY + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) < $(window).height()){
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: e.pageY + "px",
                                left: (e.pageX - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) + "px"
                            });
                        }else if((e.pageX + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollWidth) < $(window).width() && (e.pageY + $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) > $(window).height()){
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: (e.pageY - $("#orders-context-menu")[0].scrollHeight) + "px",
                                left: e.pageX + "px"
                            });
                        }else{
                            $("#orders-context-menu").css({
                                top: e.pageY + "px",
                                left: e.pageX + "px"
                            });
                        }
                        row_selected = $(this);
                    });
                }
                break;
        }
    });

    function LoadProducts(category){
        $.ajax({
            type:"GET",
            url: "/orderspage_loadproducts",
            headers:{
                "Content-type":"application/json", 
                "Accept":"application/json"
            },
            data:{
                p_category: category
            },
            success:function(response){
                $("#orders_products_table").html(response["html"]);
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
                console.error(xhr);
            }
        });
    }

    function LoadAdditions(category, product){
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/orderspage_loadadditions",
            data:{
                p_category: category,
                p_product: product
            },
            success: function(response){
                if(response["html"] == "none"){
                    $("#div-center-products-tables-additions-contents").html("");
                }else{
                    $("#div-center-products-tables-additions-contents").html(response["html"]);
                }
            },
            error:function(xhr, status, error){
                console.error(xhr);
            }
        });
    }
});


Thank you, I've never seen MutationObserver before, that is a more clean solution to the timer, because it remove immediately the attribute and not after 2 seconds, so users don't see anything. I don't use particular libraries, only jquery.
